# Evitar que combobox muestre datos si no hay seleccionado nada

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la cual filtro algunos datos mediante el combobox, y a pesar de pongo el combobox vacio me muestra los datos del primer registro. 
¿Como lo puedo solucionar?

Esta es la imagen de como me muestra algunos datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el código que uso:

```
//con este cargo a los empleados en el combobox
private void CEmpleados()
    {
        DataTable Empleados = biss.CEmpleado();
        cbEmpleado.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
        cbEmpleado.ValueMember = "idEmpleado";
        cbEmpleado.DataSource = Empleados;
        cbEmpleado.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    //con este cargo los datos y la imagen dependiendo del empleado seleccionado
    private void CDatosEmpleados()
    {
        if(cbEmpleado.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            DataTable DatosE = biss.DatosE(Convert.ToString(cbEmpleado.Text));
            foreach (DataRow row in DatosE.Rows)
            {
                pbImgEmpl.Image = Image.FromFile(row["ImagenE"].ToString());
                txtDepartamento.Text = row["Departamento"].ToString();
                txtPuesto.Text = row["Puesto"].ToString();
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: SelectedIndex = -1 para los otros combos?

Comment: añade un `else` y borra los textboxes

Comment: perdón es así, en vez de cbEmpleado.SelectedItem es cbEmpleado.Text